# Validation is not working with useState hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation, use-state

I am trying to validate my form so that it does not send if there is no name, or email input.  I am using emailjs for the form functionality and everything is working.  I've used this code before for validating forms when using material UI.  Not sure why it's not working.

```
    const form = useRef();
    

    // Validations
    const [name, setName] = useState("");
    const [error, setError] = useState("");

    const handleError = (e) => {
        setName(e.target.value);
        if (e.target.value.length < 1) {
            setError("Enter name");
        }
    }

    // send email

    const sendEmail = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        emailjs.sendForm('sID', 'tID', form.current, 'XXXX')
            .then((result) => {
                console.log(result.text);
            }, (error) => {
                console.log(error.text);
            });
        e.target.reset()
    };
           <form ref={form} onSubmit={sendEmail}>
                <Grid container>

                           
                        {error ?
                                <p style={{ color: '#D35E3C' }}>{error}</p> : ''}
                                
                     <Grid item>

                            <TextField onChange={handleError} id="standard-basic" label="Name" name="name" variant="standard" />
                     

                     </Grid>

                   
                    <Grid item>
                        <Button type="submit" />
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it by integrating the react-hook-form.

Here is the full code if anyone is interested.

```
import Grid from '@mui/material/Grid';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import React, { useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";


import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
import { Typography } from '@mui/material';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import "../css/contact.css"
import { motion } from 'framer-motion';
import emailjs from '@emailjs/browser'


const Contact = ({ pageTransitions }) => {


    const form = useRef();
    const [successMessage, setSuccessMessage] = useState("");
    const { register, handleSubmit, formState: { errors }, } = useForm();



    const serviceID = "";
    const templateID = "";
    const userID = "";

    const onSubmit = (data, r) => {
        sendEmail(
            serviceID,
            templateID,
            {
                name: data.name,
                email: data.email,
                subject: data.subject,
                message: data.message,
            },
            userID
        )
        r.target.reset();
    }




    // send email


    const sendEmail = (serviceID, templateID, variables, userID) => {
        emailjs.send(serviceID, templateID, variables, userID)
            .then(() => {
                setSuccessMessage("Sent successfully! I will contact you as soon as possible!");
            }).catch(err => console.error(`Something went wrong ${err}`));
    };



    return (
        <motion.div
            initial='out'
            animate='in'
            exit='out'
            variants={pageTransitions}>

            <form ref={form} onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
                <Grid container padding={2} sx={{
                    boxShadow: 5

                }} className="element center-form" >
                    <Grid item xs={12} sm={12} md={12}>
                        <Typography sx={{
                            textShadow: '2px 3px 5px rgb(0 0 0 / 50%)'
                        }} variant="h3">
                            Contact Me
                        </Typography>
                        <span className="error-message">
                            <p> {errors.name && errors.name.message} </p>
                            <p> {errors.email && errors.email.message} </p>
                            <p> {errors.subject && errors.subject.message} </p>
                            <p> {errors.message && errors.message.message} </p>
                        </span>

                    </Grid>



                    <Grid item xs={12} md={6}>




                        <Box>

                            <TextField sx={{
                                marginBottom: 2,

                            }} {
                                ...register("name", {
                                    required: "* Please enter your name",
                                    maxLength: {
                                        value: 20,
                                        message: "Name must not be longer than 20 characters",
                                    }
                                })
                                } fullWidth={true} id="standard-basic" label="Name" name="name" variant="standard" />

                            <br />
                            <TextField sx={{
                                marginBottom: 2
                            }} {
                                ...register("email", {
                                    required: "* Please enter a valid email",
                                    pattern: {
                                        value: /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,}$/i,
                                        message: "* Invalid Email"
                                    }
                                })
                                } fullWidth={true} id="standard-basic" label="Email" name="email" variant="standard" />

                            <br />
                            <TextField sx={{
                                marginBottom: 2
                            }} {
                                ...register("subject", {
                                    required: "* Please enter a subject",
                                    maxLength: {
                                        value: 20,
                                        message: "* Subject must not be longer than 20 characters",
                                    }
                                })
                                } fullWidth={true} id="standard-basic" label="Subject" name='subject' variant="standard" />

                        </Box>

                    </Grid>

                    <Grid item xs={12} md={6}>

                        <Box sx={{
                            marginTop: 13.2,

                        }}>

                            <TextField multiline
                                minRows={2}
                                maxRows={4} sx={{
                                    marginBottom: 2,
                                    width: '85%'



                                }} {
                                ...register("message", {
                                    required: "* Please enter a message",

                                })
                                } id="standard-basic" label="Message" name='message' variant="standard"
                            />




                        </Box>

                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item xs={12} sm={12} md={12}>
                        <Button type="submit" className='button-shadow' sx={{
                            border: 1,
                            width: '85%',



                        }} variant="outlined">Send</Button>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </form>
        </motion.div>


    )
}

export default Contact
```